# Python undefined behavior for file open / read

Tags: python

I am trying to read contents from a text file using `Python3.7` and the following is my code and I run the program on RHEL 7

I exported the required environment variable (ie Sourcepath) and all the 3 files has same contents in it

```
[sathish@WEB Exercises]$ pwd
/tmp/Exercises
[sathish@WEB Exercises]$ ls -l develop/global/src
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 skailas wheel 124 Dec 29 06:51 a.txt_bak
-rw-r--r-- 1 skailas wheel 124 Dec 29 06:54 b.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 skailas wheel 124 Dec 29 06:53 version.txt
```

```
import os
import sys

# Variable used to store file contents
file_contents = None

def readfromfile(filename):
        # Check whether the environment variable SourcePath exists
        # If not create one and assign a default value
    if not os.environ.get("Sourcepath", None):
        print("Environment variable Sourcepath does not exists")
        print("Create the environment variable and assign default value")
        os.environ["Sourcepath"] = "/tmp/Exercises"

    print("Sourcepath=", os.environ.get("Sourcepath"), os.getcwd())
    print(os.path.join(os.environ["Sourcepath"],"develop","global","src",filename))

    try:
        fh = open(os.path.join(os.environ["Sourcepath"],"develop","global","src",filename), "r")

        if ( os.stat(filename).st_size == 0):
            print("File is empty");
        else:
            # Read the contents from file and store it in a
            # global variable file_contents
            global file_contents
            print("Opened file", filename)
            file_contents = fh.read()
            print("File contents are", file_contents)
            fh.close()
            print("File closed")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("File not found for Reading ... Exiting", filename)
        sys.exit()
    except:
        print("Other Error ... Exiting")
        sys.exit()

readfromfile('b.txt')
```

Error output

```
[skailas@WEB Exercises]$  python3.7 fex.py
Environment variable Sourcepath does not exists
Create the environment variable and assign default value
Sourcepath= /tmp/Exercises /tmp/Exercises
/tmp/Exercises/develop/global/src/b.txt
File not found for Reading ... `Exiting b.txt`
```

The program mentioned above reads the file content for file `a.txt_bak`.  However, when I call the function `readfromfile('b.txt') or readfromfile('version.txt')`  it says `"FILE NOT FOUND ERROR"`

I am really confused why for 'a.txt_bak' it works and why it reports error for the other two files?  Sometimes, my program does not read content even if the file exists in same path

Am I doing anything wrong with fclose() or what am I missing?  Kindly help me to understand the issue

Comment: Do yourself a favor and open files as a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement)

Comment: Your call to `os.stat` is using `filename` without the directory; might this be where the exception comes from?

Comment: @Hans Yes.  I hope so.  Let me try and update you

Comment: @Hans You were right, os.stat was the line causing the issue.  Thanks for pointing out the issue.  I was going mad at it

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, glad that solved it.